# Diagnose `Fatal exception (0): IllegalInstruction` esp32

Tags: rust, esp32

In https://github.com/JasonKleban/rust-esp32/tree/no-idf following (I think) https://esp-rs.github.io/book/overview/comparing-std-and-no_std.html, after successful flashing I just get this in a loop:

```
Opening COM3 with speed 115200
Resetting device... done
epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0048,len:12
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x3fff0054,len:4800
load:0x40078000,len:17448
load:0x4007c428,len:4840
entry 0x4007c6a0
Fatal exception (0): IllegalInstruction
epc1=0x400d0020, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
```

How do I diagnose & fix this please?

Comment: Regarding the downvote: I have not included a code sample inline because I believe that any aspect of the entire project full of files could be critical to the question.  Besides that, the main.rs is basically empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this link to find out about [IllegalInstruction](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/fatal-errors.html#illegal-instr-msg).
But since we can't see the code I must assume the problem must be hardware.
According to the doc, it can happen if there is a bad SPI communication or bad [power supply](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3138#issuecomment-306153105).

Comment: the full project code is linked in github.  It cannot be appropriately reproduced in SO due to the project-wise nature.